# how do you use hasOwnProperty?

Tags: javascript, class, coffeescript

Can anybody explain what hasOwnProperty called on empty object does? Why use it?

```
__hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty
```

I found this when I started to develop in coffescript.. Ty

Comment: did the COFFEE parser add it to the generated code? It looks like it's just making a short-hand reference.

Comment: `hasOwnProperty` is standard javascript.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty

Comment: I find this a big bizarre, but what it does is copy the base object's `hasOwnProperty` method into a variable named `__hasProp`.  Perhaps it's done because the name is shorter?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`hasOwnProperty` is **not** called. There are no parenthesises after the function name.

`__hasProp` is a **reference** to [`Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` *<sup>[MDN]</sup>*](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) because

```
__hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty
```

is a shorter version of

```
__hasProp = Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty
```

Calling `__hasProp` now, for example in

```
__hasProp.call(someObject, 'foo')
```

is much shorter and easier to read than

```
Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty.call(someObject, 'foo')
```

---

> I founded when I start to development of coffescript.

So I assume this line was automatically generated and you might wonder why create a shortcut if no one actually has to write the code?

Having this function assigned to a variable avoids having to lookup `Object`, `Object.prototype` and `Object.prototype.hasOwnProperty` every time you want to use it. `__hasProp` is just one lookup, instead of three, and  might lead to a slight performance increase when used very often.